# R: How does one perform multiple classification in data with many levels?

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, random-forest, many-categories

I am trying to classify invoice data into UNSPSC categories. I have 2.2 million invoices and there are around 250 UNSPSC categories the data needs to be divided into. I have labeled data divided into training and test data sets.

The data has the following structure:

```
UNSPSC-code    Product        Price    Seller
809080         Apple Juice    10       Super Brugsen
802830         iPhone         6000     Electronics Center
902310         Hat            40       Funny Hats Inc
```

For each variable I have many levels (1000-12000), thus it is not feasible to use random forests for classifications. Random Forests have a limit of around 54 levels in current implementations in R. I also tried support vector machines, but they have no way of handling the memory requirements.

Is there a classification algorithm appropriate for this problem that does not have the same limitations as RF and SVM? I am currently considering doing a KNN search using a custom distance measuring algorithm, but I probably again run into the problem of memory, as KNN will require a distance matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom distance function and to do a custom Nearest Neighbour Search. It worked out pretty well with a 96 % accuracy.

Concept for distance calculation:

```
# Vectors to calculate distance between
Product        Price    Seller
Apple Juice    10       Super Brugsen
iPhone         6000     Electronics Center
Samsung S7     5000     Electronics Center

# Distance "Apple Juice" vs "iPhone"
sqrt(sum(c(1,5080,1)))
5008

# Distance "iPhone" vs "Samsung S7"
sqrt(sum(c(1,1000,1)))
1000
```

Thus the nearest neighbout for the iPhone would be the Samsung S7. Ofcause I have normalized the prices to run from 0 to 1.